# Apply my own XAML style within a particular subtree

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-style

I have the following style. As done below, it works great:

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
      <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
          <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0 0 0 0.3cm" />
          <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto" />
          <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
      </StackPanel.Resources>
      <TextBlock Text="Hello"/>
      <TextBlock Text="World"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Now comes the problem. What I really want to do is define this style in a third place, then use it in various StackPanels, including their children, in the manner of the working sample above, but not in all StackPanels. This is what I've tried. It gives a build error:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <Style x:Key="TextBlockWithBottomMargin" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0 0 0 0.3cm" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
  </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
  <TabControl>
    <!-- omitting some XAML here -->
    <TabItem Header="Help" >
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
      <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style Binding="{StaticResource TextBlockWithBottomMargin}"></Style> <!-- build error on this line -->
      </StackPanel.Resources>
      <TextBlock Text="Hello"/>
      <TextBlock Text="World"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <!-- lots more xaml here -->
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: The property 'Binding' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'. Line xxx, position 20.

Comment: Ok style class doesn't have any Binding property. U can use basedon property to create a new style from existing style. :)

Comment: see my answer how to create unnamed style from existing named style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Use*** below code to create the style at a level:

```
<StackPanel.Resources>
     <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource TextBlockWithBottomMargin}">
           <Setter .......      
     </Style>
</StackPanel.Resources>
```